How to render HTML form inputs of type number as type text?
Drupal Core renders number input fields as the expected number HTML element type. Most browser render number fields with selector arrows.
Is there a way to render number fields as text fields so the selector arrows aren't shown?

This is the ordinary behavior of the HTML number field type: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number. You could hack function preRenderNumber in core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element/Number.php, write a module providing a custom field type, or possibly, use a template hook.

So Drupal 10 doesn't give you a simple option, e.g. via an add-on module, to let the website builder decide what kind of number field they want to solve when creating the field? Why isn't there a normal (old) number field? I don't want to hack the system for that.

I gave you three options, only one of which is hacking. Also, I don't know everything. https://www.drupal.org/node/1174640 (2012) added the markup to use the HTML5 standard number field type for number fields. Any question as to "why" would be found there.

You'd be better off hiding the arrows from the number field, leaving it as a number field, so that it can still be operated on as a number field, while appearing like a text field. An example would be when entering the value in a browser - if you use a textfield, the user is given the whole keyboard. If you make it a number field, the number pad is shown on mobile when filling in the field. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_arrow_number.asp

Or, you're looking for a simple solution, maybe delete the number field and re-create it as a textfield.

I don't understand why people are downvoting this. It seems like a valid question about how to work with Drupal.

@Jaypan the first revision wasn’t that clear, I think that’s when it got the votes. Hopefully people will see the updates after the weekend
